# AngularJS / JavaScript: Order array of objects digit by digit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math

I have some special request for you all. I need a custom order / sorting for the following array of objects. The array I need to order could look like the following example:

```
//array
$scope.myArray = [
    {
        orderId: "100"
    }, {
        orderId: "02"
    }, {
        orderId: "020"
    }, {
        orderId: "90"
    }, {
        orderId: "9"
    },{
        orderId: "52222"
    }, {
        orderId: "5223"
    }, {
        orderId: "522"
    }, {
        orderId: "800"
    }, {
        orderId: "080001"
    }, {
        orderId: "0009"
    }
];
```

The main problem is, that I have to order this objects in `$scope.myArray` by the attributes `orderId` digit by digit. I already tried it with `$scope.myTest = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myTest, 'orderId', false);` but as aspected, this does not order my attribute digit by digit.

#### This is how the result should look like:

> ```
> //abstract result order
> 0009, 02, 020, 080001, 100, 522, 52222, 5223, 800, 9, 90
> ```

```
//array ordered
$scope.myArray = [
    {
        orderId: "0009"
    }, {
        orderId: "02"
    }, {
        orderId: "020"
    }, {
        orderId: "080001"
    }, {
        orderId: "100"
    },{
        orderId: "522"
    }, {
        orderId: "52222"
    }, {
        orderId: "5223"
    }, {
        orderId: "800"
    }, {
        orderId: "9"
    }, {
        orderId: "90"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the build in sort of Javascript and sort by the property as string.

```js
$scope = { myArray: [{ orderId: "100" }, { orderId: "02" }, { orderId: "020" }, { orderId: "90" }, { orderId: "9" }, { orderId: "52222" }, { orderId: "5223" }, { orderId: "522" }, { orderId: "800" }, { orderId: "080001" }, { orderId: "0009" }] };

$scope.myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.orderId.localeCompare(b.orderId);
});

console.log($scope.myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```